# HTML Mail sending tool work on localhost but not server

Tags: php

I have this simple Mail tool that allows users to input the reception subject and select html  templates that are stored in folder via drop down menu, Everything work well on my localhost, but as soon as I uploaded the Mail tool onto a server it has stopped working have no idea why code is fine as it works on local host tried to google to problem but still cannot fix it

PHP code:

```
<?php

function LoadTemplate()
    {
        $form='<select name="template">';
        $form.='<option value="" selected="selected">Select Template</option>';
            foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/templates/*') as $filename)
        {
            $form.= "<option value='" . $filename . "'>" . basename($filename) . "</option>";
        }        
        $form.='</select>';
        return $form; 
    }

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $to = $_POST['recipient'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['template'], "r") or exit("Unable to open file");
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $mail_send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if($mail_send){
     echo 'Mail Send ';
     }else{
     echo 'Try Later';
     }
}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>



    <h2>Mail</h2>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="mail.php">
        Send To:
        <input type="text" id="recipient" name="recipient">
        <br>Subject:
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject">
        <br />

            <?php require( 'mail.php'); echo LoadTemplate(); ?>
            <br>

            <input type="submit" value="Send" name='submit'>

    </form>


    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

As I said the application is very simple but it worked sooooo well on my localhost NO idea why id does not work on server could anyone suggest an solution

Comment: Have you got mail server installed on your server?

Comment: I am not sure am sorry it is someones server that gave me space to us the tool, but its a good point

Comment: Check your `$mail_send` variable. If it is true, it is accepted for mail delivery. If it s false, your server does not have mail server installed.

Comment: This is **HORRIBLY** insecure. You're directly using a user-provided filename to load a file from your filesystem, allowing a malicious user to load **ANY** file on your system that they know the path for.

Comment: You know checking headers of the email will revel where the script is also this code is open to an attacker sending any of your files to themselves.

Comment: HTML emails are very bad style: you request ultimate trust from your users. In the end, any user who is concerned the smallest bit about security and privacy must delete your mails unread. HTML emails are one of the main security thread of todays communication.

Comment: ok I have runned a var_dump($mail_send) and the result is: bool(false) so according to some answers i have to install a mail server...? how do I do that

Comment: ok thank you guys so much for this very useful information I will get in touch with server owners to resolve this matter. Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Some servers have certain functions disable that a user cannot enable them selves. Check with your hosting provider to see if they have the `mail()` function enabled.